# Error in logcat When Inserting Data into Database

Tags: android, mysql, android-layout, android-intent

I have created an Android app to insert the latitude and longitude into a locally-created database. But when I click the location button, it gives me some logcat errors on line `46`. It should pass the latitude and longitude to the database when I click location button. Could someone please help me figure this out?

Line `46` is:

```
long result = dbm.insert("location",null,cv);
```

Here is my logcat:

```
12-29 16:04:22.480: D/gralloc_goldfish(1319): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-29 16:19:55.630: D/GPS Enabled(1319): GPS Enabled
12-29 16:19:55.650: D/AndroidRuntime(1319): Shutting down VM
12-29 16:19:55.650: W/dalvikvm(1319): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb39feba8)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319): Process: com.example.gpstracking, PID: 1319
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$1.onClick(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:46)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 16:19:59.060: I/Process(1319): Sending signal. PID: 1319 SIG: 9
```

Here is my main `Activity`:

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnShowLocation;

    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    SQLiteDatabase dbm = this.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                    cv.put("latitude", gps.getLatitude());
                    cv.put("longitude", gps.getLongitude());


                    long result = dbm.insert("location",null,cv);



                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }else{
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }

            private SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: when i remove the null from that it gives me an proggramme error saying "The method insert(String, String, ContentValues) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, ContentValues"

Answer (score 2):

put proper implementation of this method:

```
   private SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

This method is returning null

```
 SQLiteDatabase dbm = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

So dbm is null, hence getting null pointer exception on line 46.

```
12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):     at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$1.onClick(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:46)
```

Follow below link to understand, how to read/write in db

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: iam really struggling here with sending latitude and longitude to local mysql database.i am new to the android and it will be much helpful if u can provide me an example.

Comment: i have already refer it.but the real problem is latitude and longitude is generate automatically using gps.so i want to know how can i pass that kind of values to Mysql db

Answer (score 1):

> 12-29 16:19:55.650: W/dalvikvm(1319): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0xb39feba8) 12-29 16:19:55.700:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 12-29 16:19:55.700:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1319): Process: com.example.gpstracking, PID: 1319
>   12-29 16:19:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1319):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I assume problem is here

```
 long result = dbm.insert("location",null,cv);
```

Why you sending `null` ??

As a result `NullPointerException` arise .

Comment: when i remove the null from that it gives me an proggramme error saying "The method insert(String, String, ContentValues) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, ContentValues"

Comment: @colombo you need to add parameter . For testing case `dbm.insert("location","Test",cv);`

Comment: @colombo Uninstall & run this app .Let me inform

Comment: still same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

just check it

```
gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);
```

gps is null so run GpsTracker in background task(Asyntask used)and if gps is not null then 
check it-

```
if(gps.canGetLocation())
```

Answer (score 0):

GPS is not getting longitude and latitude. only returning null value for lat lng.

Just Toast the value of lat and lng only.

```
double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                   // SQLiteDatabase dbm = this.getWritableDatabase();
                   // ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                   // cv.put("latitude", gps.getLatitude());
                   // cv.put("longitude", gps.getLongitude());


                   // long result = dbm.insert("location",null,cv);



                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + String.valueOf(latitude) + "\nLong: " + String.valueOf(longitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Send the String value not double.

```
String lat=String.valueOf(latitude);
String lng= String.valueOf(longitude);
```

Comment: yes thats true..when i comment those lines it works finely .but now i need to send the data to mysql databse.

Comment: u have to send it to mysql or sqlite?/

Comment: To mysql database which is created in localhost.